# Permissions Error while Magento 2 installation as Magento 2 Image for Docker

Tags: magento2, installation, docker

I have cloned Magento 2 Image for Docker from here

https://github.com/rhinos-dubai/docker-magento2.git

but when I install It asks for so many permissions as from blow screen shots:

[image]

and

[image]

I have used certain commands from terminal like:

```
rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/di
```

when I use **sudo** with above commands it says:

```
root@a6e0cb9974fa:/var/www/html# sudo rm -rf var/generation
bash: sudo: command not found
```

What should be the way out ?

Any help should be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please providing below permission to your local setup folder.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 pub var app/etc generated
```